# How to select a file from windows file explorer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Is there a way to use ShellExecute and grab the file (or rather the file path) and save it in a variable upon selecting it?

Should I use a different function all together?

I've looked at some of the other similar functions for opening the windows file explorer and all of them need a path first, before opening the window.

```
ShellExecute(NULL, L"explore", NULL, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

My goal is to open the file explorer (like ShellExecute does) and select one file, plug the path of that file into a variable and do a thing with it later.

Comment: Why do you need to use explorer to do this?

Comment: @NeilButterworth the work I inherited had hardcoded paths. I need to be able to select different file types and different files without relying on where the path is on my local machine.

Comment: @Shinji That doesn't mean that you have to use an explorer window for that.

Comment: @Swordfish 100% I know there's probably an infinite number of ways to do it, but this way made the most sense to me and I don't have much experience with any functions like this so I thought it would be a good thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [IFileDialog, IFileOpenDialog or IFileSaveDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913(v=vs.85).aspx#api)

Comment: Or [`GetOpenFileName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getopenfilenamew)/[`GetSaveFileName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getsavefilenamew) if you need to support Windows versions prior to Vista.